# PHP - Store all the results of a while loop to a single variable

Tags: php

So I need to find a way to pass the results of a while loop to a single variable.

```
$get_keywords = $db -> prepare ("SELECT keyword FROM keyword_tbl");
    $get_keywords -> execute();
$single_variable = '';
while ($row = $get_keywords -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $keywords = $row['keyword'];
    echo $keywords;
}
```

What I want is for all the data from `$keywords` say it outputs ,'keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3';
And store it all into `$single_variable`

So when I `echo $single_variable` it will display 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3'

Comment: String concatenation. Do you know what is it?

Comment: You are only fetching one record. what u trying to do/saying does not make any sense... the `while` also makes no sense at all

Comment: @masivuye Cokile I'm still quite new to programming so trying to get one column of a data through while loop is all I know. Also, I'm in quite in a schedule trying to finish my project so I don't have time to study more efficient way of getting one column

Comment: does `keyword` from your table a comma separated values?

Comment: @u_mulder As of now, no.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Sorry, I don't quite get the question. My understanding is if my keyword contains comma when it outputs, no. But I do want to put comma in between the keywords after I put it on a  single string

Comment: on your table you have a column `keyword` do u mind taking a screenshot I wanna see what's inside `keyword` column I believe u not sure what u want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$single_variable = '';
while ($row = $get_keywords -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $single_variable .= $row['keyword'].' ';        
}
echo trim($single_variable);
```

Another way:

```
$single_arr = array();
while ($row = $get_keywords -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $single_arr[] = $row['keyword'];        
}
echo implode(' ', $single_arr);
```

Update:

```
//after checking you comment, if you want to put comma in between the keywords, try 
echo implode(',', $single_arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use String

```
$get_keywords = $db -> prepare ("SELECT keyword FROM keyword_tbl");
$get_keywords -> execute();
$single_variable = '';
while ($row = $get_keywords -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $keywords = $row['keyword'];
    echo $keywords;
    $single_variable = $single_variable.$keywords." ";
}
echo $single_variable
```

If you have further operation on the keywords, Then use array to store all the keywords as

```
$single_array[] = $keyword;
```

inside the while loop (but `$single_array` will be empty array first.

**Update**
If you are new in programming please see "String concatenation in PHP"
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Above code will work for your case, see

```
$single_variable = $single_variable.$keywords." ";
```

This is very simple syntax to for string concatenation.